# Change/Rename entire webview eclipse project files and code

Tags: android, eclipse, web, webview

Please apologise me for doing this probably silly question but im working on eclipse only for 2 days and i dont want to mess this up.

I downloaded an `Webview_sample` project source code from:
SITE: https://dev.tscolari.me/2011/09/19/android-webapp-in-3-minutes/
SOURCE CODE: https://github.com/tscolari/android-webview-sample-app/downloads

I worked on this all day and finally put it to work just like i wanted it, but theres a new problem now that i cant figure it out because im having all kind of errors because i want to change the entire eclipse project files and code to my future app names because the project is not already the same and would be even more modified in the future (already tried refactor, find & replace and i always get erros i cant understand).

I can show you what i want if i started to create the project as "New" and not as "Existing" in some screens:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Getting this:**

[image]

**And at the moment i have this:**

[image]

So the files coded that i have are this:

**AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.java:**

```
package tscolari.mobile_sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mutesoft.com");
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
 }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tscolari.mobile_sample"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And thats it..

**Basically the "AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity", "tscolari.mobile_sample", "" and etc are making my life miserable.**

If someone could help me on this it would be great because my head is about to explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

copy `AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity` in your new package `your.new.package.name`. and replace first line

`package tscolari.mobile_sample;` with `package your.new.package.name;`

and then copy `main.xml` from layout folder into the layout folder of new project.

Last but not the least

add these lines in the `Manifest` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: to be honest i used a little bit of both of your answers and everything worked with no erros. But "M Moshin Naeem", i didnt understood the last part. What is the difference from what i have for what you suggested? thanks

Comment: You can upvote both answers. And chose one as your answer.
in last part I just told you to update the `manifest` file according to new package name. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Alt+Shift+R (or Refactor->Rename from the file's context menu) to rename any file, or even your project. If you follow the suggestions, all references will be updated

Comment: after "Moshin" guide i had to go one on one files to refactor them. problem fully fixed. thanks